# PowerBi API Post Rows

Tags: c#, powerbi

I am attempting to add rows to my dataset in power BI.  I have created the dataset via the API.  I can retrieve the dataset also.  On retrieving the data the properties AddRowsApiEnabled & IsRefreshable are both set TRUE.

But when i make this call

```
await _powerBiClient.Datasets.PostRowsInGroupAsync(_config.GroupId,
                    dataset.Result.Id, tableName,
                    rowsJson                    );
```

with rowsJson property being

{
    "rows": [{
        "tenantID": "8ee6eff2-8189-4df8-89be-9b28c5339cd7",
        "startTime": "2018-07-09 13:24:42.145",
        "questionID": "69c55947-0a96-4328-b1f7-a79b00dc6d73",
        "questionType": "SingleSelect",
        "correct": false,
        "mastery": 0,
        "answerAttempts": 0,
        "PossibleAnswers": 2,
        "QuestionNumber": 3
    }]
}

I get this error back

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Error parsing request for dataset sobe_wowvirtualserver|10481cc7-696f-4e0e-a4db-d4076fad866f: Did not encounter start array token or start object token for rowset"}}
```

After a bunch of searching, I figured that it is Json parsing error, as I have seen other people get the "Error parsing request for dataset sobe_wowvirtualserver" message with a different follow-up message.

any help or direction is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was sending different format in request:

```
{
  "param1" : "value1",
  "param2" : "value2"
}
```

And PowerBI endopint was waiting like this ([]):

```
[
  {
   "param1" : "value1",
   "param2" : "value2"
  }
]
```

I changed to this format and It works for me.
Check settings from PowerBI API

Answer (score 0):

I am using node to send data to PowerBI.  In the [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data-add-rows), they are sending the data as an array of bytes.

I was having the same problem as you until I noticed that my HTTP header I was using to send the data has `application/json`.  Once I removed that, no more error.

Here's my (javascript) solution (hope it helps)

```
// javascript
const datasetUrl = `${POWER_BI_ROOT_URL}/${orgName}/datasets/${datasetId}/tables/${tableName}/rows`;
const buffer = Buffer.from(typeof data === 'string' ? 'data' : JSON.stringify(data));

const rpOptions = {
  uri: datasetUrl,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: authorisation,
    // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: buffer,
};
return requestPromise(rpOptions);
```